# Inverse pulse effect

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

I am trying to create an reverse pulse effect. Something like bigger rings will become smaller or keep going inwards with animation?

At the moment I have implemented github library: https://github.com/shu223/PulsingHalo

This is pretty good and works fine but only thing I want to modify is change the rings to inwards.

I tried reading several posts on SO but didn't find any that could help my scenario. Most of the posts are for pulse effect but not reverse pulse.

Can someone suggest me any library or native code that could be helpful for such animation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Invert the scale. change lines 133 and 134 in PulsingHaloLayer.m

```
scaleAnimation.fromValue = @1.0;
scaleAnimation.toValue = @(self.fromValueForRadius);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. With the suggested change, the proper effect of animation is lost, it is kind of blink effect now. Seems like some more values has to be changed.